# Image of unit ball precompact implies bounded

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, banach-spaces

I need to prove that if the image of the unit ball $X_1$ of a Banach space $X$ along an operator $A:X\rightarrow Y$ is precompact, $A$ is bounded.

Is my solution correct?

$\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|_Y=\sup_{A(X_1)}\|v\|_Y=\sup_{\overline{A(X_1)}}\|v\|_Y=\max_{\overline{A(X_1)}}\|v\|_Y<\infty.$ The third equality is by continuity of the norm and the fourth is by the precompactness of $A(X_1)$.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. What are you not sure about ? It is by the way not necessary to assume that $X$ is a Banach space.

Comment: @Epsilon just making sure :) [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858017/proving-an-operator-is-compact-exercise) is giving me a hard time though :(