# Proving an operator is compact exercise

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, compact-operators

Suppose $(a_{ij})_{i,j\in \mathbb N}$ satisfy $\sum_{i,j}|a_{ij}|^2<\infty$ and define $A:\ell ^2 \rightarrow \ell ^2$ by $(Ax)_i)=\sum _j a_{ij}x_j$. I need to prove $A$ is compact.

Unfortunately, I really have not idea what to do here. I don't see how playing around with the $\ell^2$ norm will be of any use. On the other hand, using $\|\cdot\|_2\leq \|\cdot\|_1$ only gives me $\|Ax_n-Ax_m\|_2\leq \sum _{ij}|a_{ij}||x_j|$ which doesn't seem to help either. I'm pretty sure I'm not supposed to use this equality anyway, but I don't even have intuition for why the operator should be compact. (My strategy was to take a bounded sequence $x_k$ from the unit ball and show its image has a convergent subsequence.)

Comment: Sounds like you need to use the fact that compact operators form a closed set in the space of bounded operators.

Comment: @QiyuWen could you elaborate?

Comment: You can approximate $A$ by a sequence of operators with finite-dimensonal ranges (hence compact). As their limit, $A$ itself will also be compact.

Comment: @QiyuWen ah, yes, this is exactly what Epsilon is saying. I don't know how to prove the approximation he suggests though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand what $A$ looks like. It acts as an infinite matrix $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ on your elements of $\ell^2$. Since $\ell^2$ is a Hilbert space you know that $A$ is compact if it is a limit of finite-rank operators. You can show that $A$ is the limit of $P_nAP_n$ where $P_n$ is the projection on the span of the first $n$ standard basis vectors.

Comment: Why not just $AP_n$? I'm not sure how to prove this...

Comment: If you cut down the input vector to the first $n$ entries you can still get an infinite dimensional range. So you also have to cut down the output. Then $P_nAP_n$ has finite dimensional range and it corresponds to the matrix $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^n$, i.e. the upper left block of size $n$ of $A$. Since $\sum_{i,j} \lvert a_{i,j} \rvert ^2 < \infty$ you can show that $\lVert A-P_nAP_n \rVert_2 \to 0$.

Comment: I see. Should think of this $P_nAP_n$ as a "degenerate base change" by omitting vectors?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that, but now it should be a question of a straightforward calculation.

Comment: $\sum_{i,j} \lvert a_{i,j} \rvert ^2 < \infty$ just says $A$ is bounded, right?

Comment: I'm trying to show $\|P_nAP_n-A\|\rightarrow 0$ but I don't see where to use  $\sum_{i,j} \lvert a_{i,j} \rvert ^2 < \infty$.. The sums $\sum_j a_{ij}x_j$ are always squared... Am I supposed to use the $\sum _ia_i^2\leq (\sum _i a_i)^2$?

Comment: I will first answer your first question: $\sum_{i,j} \lvert a_{ij} \rvert^2 < \infty$ implies boundedness of $A$ but it is clearly not equivalent to that statement. For example the identity on $\ell^2$ is bounded but its coefficients are not summable, since the identity corresponds to the operator $A$ with $a_{ij} = \delta_{ij}$. And clearly the identity is not compact.

Comment: Thanks! I just figured that out myself. Still don't see where the condition $\sum_{i,j} \lvert a_{ij} \rvert^2 < \infty$ pops in, and I ran into a similar problem [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858104/prove-multiplication-by-sequence-is-a-compact-operator) (I showed my work).

Comment: By simply calculating you can show that $\lVert Ax - P_nAP_nx \rVert_2^2 \leq \sum_{i,j=n+1}^\infty \lvert a_{ij} \rvert ^2$ if $\lVert x \rVert_2 \leq 1$. But since the $a_{ij}$ are square summable the estimate tends to $0$ if $n$ gets large.

Comment: Uh, sorry, I just don't see this calculation. Just for $x$: $\|Ax\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_i(\sum_ja_{ij}x_j)^2}$. How do you get $\|x_2\|_2$ out of here?

Comment: Is it $\|Ax\|_2=\sqrt{\sum_i(\sum_ja_{ij}x_j)^2}\leq \sum_j x_j^2\sum_ia_{ij}^2=\|x\|_2\sum_{ij}a_{ij}^2$?

Comment: You have to invoke $P_nAP_nx$ if you want to calculate the norm of the difference.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just talking about the calculation even for just $x$. The difference follows from that. Is my calculation for $x$ correct?

Comment: If $\lVert  x \rVert_2 \leq 1$ you know that $\sum_i \lvert x_i \rvert^2 \leq 1$. Hence, every term $\lvert x_j \rvert$ or $x_j^2$ is bounded by $1$.

Comment: @Epsilon I asked about this [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858180/simple-norm-inequality). I'm also having trouble following this, since I can't see how $|x_j|\leq 1$ resolves everything.