# Prove multiplication by sequence is a compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

Let $c_0(\mathbb N)$ be the space of sequence in $\mathbb C$ whose limit is zero, equipped with the $\ell^\infty$ norm. Let $u_n$ be a sequence in $\mathbb C$ and define the operator $A$ taking a sequence $x_n$ in $\ell ^\infty (\mathbb N)$ to the sequence $u_nx_n$. I need to prove $A\in B(\ell^\infty(\mathbb N), c_0(\mathbb N)$ iff it's in $K(\ell^\infty(\mathbb N), c_0(\mathbb N)$.

$\impliedby$ always holds, and for $\implies$, I think the strategy is the same as [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1858024/353191), but again, I'm having trouble showing why boundedness is needed for compactness. So letting $P_n$ be the operator that truncates after the $(n+1)^\text{th}$ place, I want to show $\|P_nAP_n-A\|\rightarrow 0$. Now

$$\|P_nAPx-Ax\|_\infty=\ \sup_{\|x\|=1}\|(0,\dots,0,u_{n+1}x_{n+1},\dots)\|_\infty $$
so if $u_nx_n\rightarrow 0$ I think that alone suffices to show the RHS tends to zero, and in fact the convergence  *implies* boundedness. Finally, $P_nAP_n$ is compact because it has finite rank, so $A$ is compact as a norm-limit of compact operators.

Did I actually need $A$ to be bounded?

Comment: If $A$ is bounded you should be able to show that $(u_n) \in c_0(\mathbb N)$. The rest works well, I think. Actually, if you know that $ux = (u_nx_n)$ is in $c_0(\mathbb N)$ you know that $\lvert u_nx_n \rvert$ gets eventually arbitrary small and hence the supremum you write down gets arbitrary small.

Comment: @Epsilon Ahhh I'm confused again. If $A\in B(\ell^\infty(\mathbb N), c_0(\mathbb N)$, then $(u_nx_n)\in c_0(\mathbb N)$, so why can't we just say $\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|(0,\dots,0,u_{n+1}x_{n+1},\dots)\|_\infty\rightarrow 0$? Why do you suggest showing $(u_n) \in c_0(\mathbb N)$?

Comment: @Epsilon exactly, so was I initially right in saying you *don't* need boundedness?

Comment: Note that $\lVert (0,0,\cdots,0,u_{n+1}x_{n+1},\cdots) \rVert_{\infty} \leq \lVert x \rVert _\infty \sup_{i>n} \lvert u_n \rvert \leq \sup_{i>n} \lvert  u_n \rvert $ if $\lVert x \rVert \leq 1$. This proves that $\lVert P_nAP_n -A \rVert \leq \sup_{i>n} \lvert u_n \rvert$. So I think you need boundedness of $A$ to show that $(u_n) \in c_0(\mathbb N)$.

Comment: @Epsilon right, that's for going by your original suggestion to show $(u_n) \in c_0(\mathbb N)$, but as you say, if $ux = (u_nx_n)$ is in $c_0(\mathbb N)$ the supremum gets arbitrarily small. So aren't we getting away without boundedness of $A$?

Comment: @Epsilon okay. As for showing boundedness implies $(u_n) \in c_0(\mathbb N)$, I am still confused - it seems the fact $A$ lands in $c_0(\mathbb N)$ is enough to imply $u_n\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Yes, if you take $x = (1,1,1,\cdots)$ you see that $Ax = u$. So $u \in c_0(\mathbb C)$. So one could also say $A \in L(\ell^\infty,c_0) \iff A \in K(\ell^\infty,c_0)$ where $L$ denotes complex linear operators.

Comment: @Epsilon so boundedness is not needed after all! Thanks for all your time! If you want to post anything as an answer I'd love to accept!