# Simple norm inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, operator-theory, normed-spaces, compact-operators

Trying to follow the comments to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1858017/proving-an-operator-is-compact-exercise/1858024?noredirect=1#comment3804234_1858024) I am struggling very much to understand how to simplify $\|Ax\|_2=\sup_{\|x\|_2=1}\sqrt{\sum_i(\sum_ja_{ij}x_j)^2}$ to arrive at an $x$-free bound. Can anyone explain how *exactly* this goes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$
 \left (\sum_j a_{ij} x_j \right)^2 = \lvert \langle (a_{ij})_j, (x_j)_j \rangle \rvert^2 \leq \lVert (a_{ij})_j \rVert_1^2 \rVert x\lVert_1^2
$$
So, if $x$ is summable, you know that $\lVert x \rVert_1 < \infty$ and you can get rid of the norm of $x$ in the estimate.

By $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle$ I mean the inner product in $\ell^1$.

Comment: So just a sneaky Cauchy Schwarz, cool.